# Are PIX firewalls still supported by Cisco?

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-pix

I was told by a salesman at a hosting company to be wary of anyone trying to use a PIX firewall in my hosting solution because Cisco doesn't support them anymore or offer security updates. Is that true? His was the only company out of 5 that *didn't* include a PIX firewall in their proposal. So is everyone else giving me out-of-date and possibly insecure hardware or is the salesman full of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**This post from Cisco**](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps5708/ps5709/ps2030/qa_eos_for_sale_for_cisco_pix_products_customer.html) seems to clarify the dates a bit

looks like certain extended support is still around, but purchasing one has pretty much ended

that said, the ASA is a worthy replacement and still going strong I believe

Comment: Morever, the ASA line was designed to replace the PIX line.

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of people still use the name PIX for ASA gear as well, so you may just want to clarify with them the actual product being used.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to do. PIX is still good.515e and 535 even the old 506e .

As I said before it depends on your requirements of design.I still use and deploy them.

Configure them good and they are solid.

Devices and age ,old or new is not the problem.

It is the person configuring them and whether it supports what you want to do.

People think ,they spend more ,they get good .that is a  no no.

Think about the old school. Everybody is moving back to command line.before we ran away.

Even exchange 2010 has power shell now.

So work with your requirements.If there design meets what you want .

whether they use helicopter ,use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Officially, the PIX 500 series is end-of-sale.  Last chance to attach a new service contract with Cisco was July '09.  End of support outright is July 27, 2013.  As already stated, the ASA is the new PIX.

Answer (score 1):

An ASA will do everything the PIX did and then some, so it the replacement.  You can pretty much drop a PIX config onto an ASA and it will run, so there's no way I'd buy a PIX today.